# Java split around numbers

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string in java like:

```
 "Corrected Acceleration 20130816_053116_RCS2_21 GNS Science"
```

I am looking to get the last part of the number sequence. It is the number after the last underscore.

In this case:

```
21
```

More examples are

```
 "Corrected Acceleration 20130346_053116_RCS2_15 GNS Science"
```

Want `15`

```
 "Corrected Acceleration 20130346_053116_RCS2_13 GNS Science"
```

Want `13`

```
 "Acceleration 123214_05312323_RCS2_40 GNS Science"
```

Want `40`

This format will stay the same. The variations will be different numbers and possibly the front substring `Corrected` might be missing.

How would I go about extracting this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Have you attempted to write a regex?

Comment: What *total output* do you want? What if there are *two* such numbers in the input?

Comment: You might need to define the format a bit better, is the format "a name consisting of multiple words and spaces, then a number with underscores..." or is it a "word space word space, then a number with underscores..." is just one potential problem.

Comment: Can you provide a few more sample strings so we can get an idea of what will vary and what will stay the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_[0-9]+ ");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
matcher.find();

// Note the + 1 and - 1 here to get rid of the leading underscore and the trailing space
int number = Integer.parseInt(text.subString(matcher.start() + 1, matcher.end() - 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This SHOULD get what you need. Please bear in mind i have not tested thism but the logic should work:

```
String test = "Corrected Acceleration 20130816_053116_RCS2_21 GNS Science";
int lastUnderScore = test.lastIndexOf("_");
test = test.substring(lastUnderScore + 1);
int numLength = test.indexOf(" ");
int number = Integer.valueOf(test.substring(0, numLength));
```

1. Find the last instance of '_'
2. cut string back to start at the beginning of the number
3. find the position of the first ' ' (This will now be after the number you need)
4. cut string down to before the space and cast to an integer.